# Unable to delete an item from a collection from FireBase with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to delete a "food" from a collection from a users' account. I create a deleteFoodEntry function within my AuthViewModel and then I have a private func within my AddFoodView file. Within the terminal it says it successfully deletes, but when I check on FireBase itself, it has in fact NOT been deleted out of the database. I have no clue how to solve this issue. I can add foods and create accounts perfectly fine to FireBase, but when it comes to deleting a certain food out of the database it does not work. I have attached the addFood func and the deleteFood func along with my private func for deleting the food within my list.

```
func addFoodEntry(_ foodEntry: FoodEntry) async throws {
        guard let userId = userSession?.uid else {
            throw NSError(domain: "UserNotLoggedIn", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
        }
        
        do {
            let _ = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userId).collection("foods").addDocument(from: foodEntry)
            print("Food entry added successfully.")
            
            await updateCaloriesConsumed()
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to add food entry: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            throw error
        }
    }
    
    func deleteFoodEntry(documentId: String) async throws {
        guard let userId = userSession?.uid else {
            throw NSError(domain: "UserNotLoggedIn", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
        }

        let documentReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userId).collection("foods").document(documentId)
        
        do {
            try await documentReference.delete()
            print("Food entry deleted successfully.")
            
            await updateCaloriesConsumed() // Assuming you want to recalculate calories after deletion.
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to delete food entry: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            throw error
        }
    }

private func deleteFood(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            // Capture the ID of the entry to delete
            let foodEntryId = foodEntries[index].id
            
            Task {
                do {
                    // Attempt to delete the entry from Firestore
                    try await authViewModel.deleteFoodEntry(documentId: foodEntryId)
                    
                    // Upon successful deletion, update UI and data model on the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.foodEntries.remove(at: index)
                        // Update the calories consumed based on the modified list
                        Task {
                            await authViewModel.updateCaloriesConsumed()
                        }
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    // Handle errors on the main thread if needed
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("Error deleting food entry: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Searched online and could not find a valid solution.

Comment: Don’t mix GCD with async/await you probably have threading issues. DispatchQueue and Task don’t mix

Comment: I just changed out DispatchQueue and made it all strictly Tasks. Still does not work. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: There's a lot of UI logic here that we can't see. If you call `Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("hardcoded UID").collection("foods").document("hardcoded document ID").delete()`, *does* it delete the document?

Comment: We would need an MRE to fully help. There are many points of failures. Is the id actually the document id or a UUID? Do the offsets actually match the food entries as the items are being deleted? That floating Task in there can be a huge issue with this. Note that as you “remove” from food entries the index actually changes.